# Python - get maximum dictionary key based on key attribute

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes, key, max

I have a `Node` class defined as follows (I only copied the relevant code for simplification):

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.neighbours = []
```

I also have a dictionary that has `Node` objects as key, and the key-node's list of neighbours as value for each key.

```
successorTable = {
    Node(0, 1): [Node(1, 0)],
    Node(1, 0): [Node(0, 1)],
    # and so on ...
}
```

Now what I would like to do is to get the dictionary's key (Node object) having the maximum value of `x` and the key having the maximum value of `y`

So I basically am trying to get the following result:

```
# maxXNode -> Node(1, 0)
# maxYNode -> Node(0, 1)
```

Comment: does your Node object have a `__hash__` special method? Otherwise that will not work as you intend.

Comment: Why do you need `successorTable`? Isn't that what `Node.neighbours` is for? That is, any time you would use `successorTable[x]`, you could just say `x.neighbors` instead.

Comment: Successors are a node's neighbours in one specific direction. That's why I need `successorTable` which is a graph's attribute, not a node's. I would however use `Node.neighbours` in a non-oriented Graph.

Comment: @jdehesa, Your answer gave me a clue, though I had to modify it. Thanks.
Here is the modified version:
`max_key_x = max(successorTable.keys(), key=lambda n: n.y).y`

`max_key_y = max(successorTable.keys(), key=lambda n: n.x).x`

Answer (score 2):

### Your problem

First, for you problem you can do this.

```
max_x = max(successorTable.keys(), key=lambda n: n.x)
max_y = max(successorTable.keys(), key=lambda n: n.y)
```

### Other problems

Then a word on your code.

I suggest you be careful with using your `Node`'s as dictionary key as you didn't define `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods.

```
d = {}
d[Node(0, 0)] = 0
d[Node(0, 0)] # raises a KeyError
```

By default, an object is hashed and compared by its id, so two nodes with the same coordinates will not hash to the same value. You might want to fix this like so.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self.neighbours = []

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.x, self.y) == (other.x, other.y)
```

We use `_x`, `_y` and `property` to emphasize the fact that those attributes should not be updated as they are used for hashing.